# Comparison of the cardinal numbers of union and index set

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

The question that I am trying to solve is the following:

Let $\{X_i\}$ be any infinite class of countable sets indexed by the elements $i$ of an index set $I$, and show that the cardinal number of $\cup_iX_i$ is less than or equal to the cardinal number of $I$.

If $I$ is a countable set, then since $\cup_iX_i$ is also countable, the mentioned cardinal numbers are the same. If $I$ is uncountable, in the given hint, it is said that due to Zorn's lemma, $I$ can be represented as the union of a disjoint class of countably infinite subsets.

I understand the hint, but I couldn't use it. Probably, we need to find a one-to-one or onto mapping between $\cup_iX_i$ and $I$. But, I didn't figure it out. Any help is very welcomed.

Comment: Is there a reason why the following standard argument is not allowed? $$\left| \bigcup_{i \in I} X_i \right| \leqslant \sum_{i \in I} |X_i| \leqslant \sum_{i \in I} \aleph_0 = |I| \cdot \aleph_0 = \max \{ |I|, \aleph_0 \} = |I|$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By your hint, lets consider the partitioning

$$I=\bigcup_{k\in K} I_k$$

where each $I_k$ is countable, and they are pairwise disjoint. Since each $X_i$ is countable then it follows that $\bigcup_{i\in I_k}X_i$ is countable for any $k\in K$. In particular there's a bijection between $\bigcup_{i\in I_k}X_i$ and $I_k$ itself. Thus

$$I=\bigcup_{k\in K} I_k\equiv\bigsqcup_{k\in K}\bigcup_{i\in I_k}X_i\geq \bigcup_{i\in I}X_i$$

Note the disjoint union "$\bigsqcup$" symbol and "$\geq$" inequality. The first one follows by applying the bijection (each $I_k$ has to be replaced by a disjoint copy of $\bigcup_{i\in I_k}X_i$), while the second one because of duplicates (that appeared due to the disjoint union). And this completes the proof.